# Is it possible to maintain WebRTC connection after disconnecting from the internet after signalling phase?

Tags: webrtc

If WebRTC connection is established between two peers in local network, can we maintain it, after losing connection to the internet? It seems possible, as it's peer-to-peer.

Comment: if the machines are on the same local network, then I don't see how losing outside access would affect connections between the two.

Comment: Thanks - I'll continue to develop this topic :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The peers connect directly using the private ip-address in the same network. They do not need to go through the public IP address, which will require internet.

Comment: OK, then why https://apprtc.appspot.com/ is disconnecting after a while? @obscure-geek says that it's some internal socket timeout, but why do such problem exists if it's capable of maintaining connection

Comment: During the peer-to-peer communication, RTCPeerConnection also performs   periodic liveness checks, to monitor the connection. It involves the ICE candidates which have public IPs returned by STUN and TURN servers. Without internet it fails to perform this check & returns iceConnectionState as "disconnected". 
You can also confirm by checking the  browser console of  [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com)

Comment: OK, so can we just ignore `iceConnectionState` and sustain connection, or is it general rule of RTCPeerConnection that it will break when it will discover that `iceConnectionState` state is `disconnected`?

Answer (score 0):

Even after loosing internet connectivity, the connection is maintained for a certain time. I believe this may be some internal socket timeout. A simple experiment on https://apprtc.appspot.com/ gave the timeout to be around 15-20 seconds.